# How to approach hurdle models with multiple covariates in R

Tags: model-selection

I have count data that I standardized into continuous data (density) because the area surveyed varied among sites.  I have several sites in which the count was zero. The probability of observing a non-zero was 0.21 so I wanted to use a hurdle model approach. I also recorded several potential explanatory variables for each site. I would like to test a suite of candidate models to address which variables best explains my response and I am unsure how to conduct this with a hurdle model.

1) Do I separate the two models and select for the best logistic model for observations of zeros and a linear model for density and then run a hurdle model with the two best models or can I run multiple hurdle models and just use the model with the best AIC (not sure how to do this step)?

2) Do I have to use count data for a hurdle model?

3) If I can use continuous data, how?

Thanks for the assistance!

MD

Comment: Standardizing a discrete variable doesn't make it continuous; it's a discrete mixture. You could account for the area by using an offset (with a log-link), or if you're not sure the count will be directly proportional to area, by including it as a predictor (whose supposed relationship you can check for reasonableness via diagnostics, for example).

Answer (score 1):

A standard hurdle model is a mixture model consisting of a logistic regression model modelling the zeros and a poisson model modelling the counts. Therefore, you would have to use the count data in order to fit the model. Seeing that the sites differed in area, I would use the area of the site as an offset in your poisson model. This should solve your second and third question.

In order to select the best hurdle model, maybe you could try a backwards selection procedure after incorporating all relevant predictors in both models, unless you have sound knowledge of which predictors will be associated with which part of the mixture model.

Comment: +1. I believe that what model functions call an _offset_ is also known (outside of model functions) as the _exposure_? Just in case that clarifies anything.